# Android EditText blocks parent SwipeMenu

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Working on this app on which have some SwipeMenuListViews.

One of those has an edit menu item like this.

[image]

Now as you can imagine on Edit click should make the item editable.
And this is not working out at all.

Tried a lot and on what I found was that I needed to use an EditText view and so I did. The problem I've got by using them is that these are blocking the parent swipe menu.

I need the SwipeMenu (where the EditViews are child from)to have some sort of priority (not sure if this possible) OR enable all listeners on the EditText views.

**ListView with swipe menus - ContactsFragment.java**

```
SwipeMenuListView listView = (SwipeMenuListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view);

contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getContext(), contacts);
listView.setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector);
listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter); 
SwipeMenuCreator swipeMenu = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

     @Override
     public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
         SwipeMenuItem editItem = new SwipeMenuItem(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
         editItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xC9, 0xC9, 0xCE)));
         editItem.setWidth(Dimension.dpTopx(getActivity(), 90));
         editItem.setTitle("Edit");
         editItem.setTitleSize(18);
         editItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
         menu.addMenuItem(editItem);

         SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
         deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9, 0x3F, 0x25)));
         deleteItem.setWidth(Dimension.dpTopx(getActivity(), 90));
         deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete);
         menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
      }
 };
```

I already tried these on each EditText **- ContactAdapter.java**

```
    contactEmail.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    contactEmail.setEnabled(false);
    contactEmail.setOnClickListener(null);
    contactEmail.setFocusable(false);
```

And after spending some hours searching my creativity is emptied and that's why I need some help from here.

Comment: I can think of a way to make it editable is put invisible `EditText` behind `TextView` and when user click on edit button make the `EditText` visible and pass it the `TextView` value and when user done editing make the `EditText` invisible and pass the user entered value to `TextView`,  got me?

Comment: @Anders Thanks for response, yeah ill got you! I though this would be a ugly solution (because I have three of these listviews each containing a lot of items :p)

Comment: well then you really need to find a better solution because its just a hack :)

Comment: I am afraid so. In the mean time I'll use this hack. Thanks for thinking with me!